# Django - Model.py

Tags: django, database

Just a simple question.

After I connect my django app to a remote database, I don't need to use Model.py to create tables in the database, then what is the function for Model.py at that moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the Django ORM, you'll need to create models in the models.py file that match your remote database.  If you don't want django creating or deleting tables on this DB, the managed=False option needs to be set for each model. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#managed

Answer (score 1):

As you said after running migrations all tables in models.py file will be created. Later on, if you want to do some database operations, you may be using Django ORM. If you don't have models.py you won't be able to do such operations.

For example:
To create an entry to the table **MyModel**.

```
from your_app.models import MyModel
MyModel.objects.create(<field_name>=<value>)
```

I hope this gives you some idea.

Comment: so, if I need a Employee table, do I still need to create a Employee model?

Comment: one answer to your question is "yes," but the more involved answer is that if you're working in django you should ideally be thinking more about Models than you worry about tables - the goal of an ORM is to structure your data around Objects and let the framework worry about what happens at the level of the database (of course this is not always possible, but for the majority of apps you will rarely need to worry about the database schema).